# Maximum element of Perron vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Suppose $A$ is an entrywise nonnegative matrix that is symmetric, irreducible and has a zero diagonal. By Perron-Frobenius theorem, the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ is an eigenvalue and $A$ has, up to scaling, a unique entrywise positive eigenvector $v$ (i.e. the *Perron vector*) for this eigenvalue.

Let $r_i$ denotes the $i$-th row sum of $A$. In general, the maximum row sum of $A$ and the maximum entry of $v$ occur in different positions. For example, when
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&0&0&2\\ 0&0&3&2\\ 0&3&0&3\\ 2&2&3&0},
$$
the Perron vector is $(0.2067,\ 0.5236,\ 0.5908,\ 0.5780)^\top$. Therefore the maximum entry of the Perron vector is the third one, but the maximum row sum of $A$ occurs in the fourth row. However, in the computer experiments that I have carried out, this kind of exceptional cases are relatively infrequent. So, it seems that by imposing some mild conditions, one may force $\arg\max_i r_i=\arg\max_i v_i$. Now my question is:

> Under what conditions can we conclude that $\arg\max_i r_i=\arg\max_i v_i$?

(Let's ignore the pathological cases where $\arg\max_i r_i$ or $\arg\max_i v_i$ are not unique.) This question arose when I was pondering what could happen if we apply Google style ranking to a weighted *undirected* graph. If $\arg\max_i r_i=\arg\max_i v_i$, there is no need to compute the Perron vector if I only want to find the highest-ranked member.

Comment: the positive entries matrices are the one invariating the positive cone. The generators of that cone are unique up to positive proportionality ( and permutation).wonder if your statement is invariant under the conjugation by monomial matrices with positive entries; but,... you probably figured it out a while ago